# What type of 4" wooden board is selected for siding trim?

Tags: wood, siding

What type of wooden board is to be purchased from Home Depot to replace the board in the photographs?  I think it is approximately 4 or 5" wide.  I assume that it is or should be pressure treated.

[image]

Comment: Trim (corners, frieze boards, etc.) are part of a home's siding. let's not get too pedantic.

Comment: You might consider using PVC trim. It doesn't rot. It only comes in white, though, and you're not supposed to paint it...

Comment: @FreeMan You can paint PVC trim.  In fact, you may want to go over some of it with white paint just to keep the non-factory cut surfaces from accumulating grime because they're not a solid smooth like the factory surfaces.

Comment: What additional details are needed to clarify this question?

Answer (score 3):

Hard to say with such a photo, but a big box or a real lumberyard will have a range of possibilities.

First, it probably shouldn’t be pressure treated, as those don’t paint particularly well. PT is also more commonly used for applications with ground contact.

At the store you’ll find exterior grade, pre-primed options in pine, redwood, possibly cedar. These can be fingerjointed or not. They can be knotty or clear.

Prime the cuts and backs of any siding and it’ll last reasonably well.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  How would you choose between pine, redwood etc?  Assume home is in North Florida.  I would like to install items for longevity.

Comment: Budget is usually an issue, but if you only have a couple of bits to replace, I’d suggest you get something clear of knots, not fingerjointed and either cedar or redwood (whatever you have locally). Pine is good but not as naturally rot resistant as others.

Comment: There might be cypress in Florida as well.

Answer (score 2):

Wood siding and trim can be of several common species:

- Fir
- Cedar
- Redwood

I've listed these in order of ascending rarity (and therefore cost). Cedar and redwood contain natural tannins which resist rot. They'll last longer. Fir is a less expensive alternative which can last a long while if sealed well with paint or other coatings, and when not in a perpetually damp environment.

Your siding is either fir or cedar veneer on fir plywood. It's hard to say without seeing it up close or smelling it. I'd use whatever those happen to be for your replacement trim, but you could just get cedar to be safe. If I had to guess I'd say that a 1x6 was ripped in appropriate widths to build that inside corner assembly, but that could be a 1x4 also. (Actual thickness will be somewhere in the 3/4" to 7/8" range--cedar tends to be milled thicker.)

If you're painting with solid color you can also consider vinyl (PVC). It can be found with a molded texture to simulate rough-sawn lumber.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a trim board. Take a tape measure, get the dimensions and go to your local hardware store.

If you go to Home Depot or other similar store and ask for a trim board, they will point to the pile of 1x pine boards (these are 3/4" x different nominal widths, e.g. 1x5, etc.). No need to make it more complicated than that.

Comment: The OP didn't ask to be tutored in the different types of wood used in house exteriors. The OP asked for what to ask for when walking into Home Depot.